# Generic method and linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, join, where-clause

I have 2 tables in my project:

```
TableEnvelope{
 ID int primary key,
 EnvelopeNumber int,
 .
 .
 .    
}

TableCheck{
ID int primary key,
CMC7 varchar
.
.
.
}
```

I have to "block" each document to a specific user, because 2 users can't see the same information.
So I have my table:

```
TableLock{
ID int primary key,
IDEnvelope int,
IDCheck int
UserId int
.
.
.
}
```

I'm trying to do a Generic method to take N rows in my table and lock it but I can't.

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> LockDocument<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> colEntity, int countRows)
{
  TEntity objEntity = default(TEntity);
  Database db = new Database();


  var vQuery = (from entity in db.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>()
               Join tableLock in db.TableLock
                 // I have problems here.
                  on entity.ID equals tableLock.IDEntity
               where entity.ID not in tableLock.IDEntity).select().Take(countRows)
 }
```

How can I do this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: So users own the relationship between envelopes and checks not the checks or envelopes themselves?

Comment: @Jodrell The relationship is between envelopes and checks but a user can get either an envelope or a check, so I have to add in the tableLock The Id of the document that he is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must constrain your TEntity to provide additional information to your method. For example you can define interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int ID { get; }
}
```

And implement this interface by all entities you want to pass to your method. Now you can change the definition of your method to:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> LockDocument<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> colEntity, 
                                                 int countRows)
    where TEntity : IEntity
{ ... }
```

This will tell your method that it accepts only types implementing `IEntity` and you can use any property or method defined by `IEntity` in your method = you will have access to `entity.ID`.